# How to make a property of a class accessible to another certain class without making it public?

Tags: c#, class, access-modifiers

In the code below, I want to access `StackElement.below` in `LinkStack.Pop()`, so I cannot decorate `StackElement.below` as private. However I also don't want to make it public because it's not safe if any other class can access the property. What should I do then? Thanks in advance.

```
public class StackElement
{
    public int value;
    public StackElement below;
}
public class LinkStack
{
    private StackElement topElement;
    private int count, capacity;

    void Pop()
    {
        topElement = topElement.below;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to move one class inside the other? Are you trying to protect from access _outside_ the assembly or _anything_ that is not that one named class, even inside the same assembly?

Comment: I tried to move StackElement into LinkStack and make it private class, but this way I will also lose access to StackElement.value outside the class, which is not what I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to restrict the `below` field to only the `StackElement` and the `LinkStack` class, then it's best to put the `LinkStack` class inside `StackElement`.

```
public class StackElement
{
    public int value;
    private StackElement below; // now private

    public class LinkStack
    {
        private StackElement topElement;
        private int count, capacity;
        void Pop()
        {
            topElement = topElement.below;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if that is architecturally appropriate for your application or not.

If you only need to protect the field from access *outside* the assembly, then make it `internal` instead.

```
internal StackElement below;
```